# CPU barely utilized when compressing with 7-zip

Tags: compression, archiving

When I try to compress with 7z maximum compression, my CPU utilization is under 20%. Only one of the cores is 100% loaded, and not even 100% of the time.

I'm on a fast SSD, so it's definitely not bottlenecked by the disk.

These are the commands I've tried:

```
7z a -mx=9 -m0=LZMA2 -mmt12 test.7z *.mkv
7z a -mx=9 -m0=LZMA2 -mmt=12 test.7z *.mkv
7z a -mx=9 -m0=LZMA2 -mmt=on test.7z *.mkv
```

This is the CPU utilization graph:

[image: Graph]

Comment: Depending on how it's implemented it might just be single threaded. The compression algorithm being used might also influence that behavior. The graph doesn't really show much as it's unclear what other software was running while running 7z.

Comment: Odd, LZMA2 should use all cores. Does 7z exhibit the same behaviour when you archive via the UI 'Add to Archive' dialog?

Comment: Yes, same if I use the UI.

Answer (score 3):

I see the same behaviour with the `-mx9` flag applied.

With that flag removed I see all cores being fully utilized.

The "ultra" compression (`mx9`) algorithm is doing a more exhaustive and memory intensive search and so is being constrained by memory bandwidth.

Using `-mx5` or `-mx7` results in more CPU usage.

---

Indeed, from [this page](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm#7Z) it appears that Ultra (9) and High (7) settings results in significantly larger dictionaries and other settings on the data to check for compression. This will slow down compression a massive amount and as the data is in memory it is memory bandwidth that is the limiting factor.

---

Using larger dictionary sizes will significantly impact compression speed due to the fact that for every set of bytes on the file to be compressed it now has to search a dictionary 2 or 4 times the size using algorithms that may end up searching the data set multiple times in different ways. This could result in an exponential slowdown as memory requirements increase.

Ultra also changes the dictionary search algorithm, presumably to one that is more efficient in terms of compression if not speed - if it were faster then it would be the default. This will slow it down still further.

Compression algorithms are often written as a series of compromises based on the state of current hardware. Settings are tuned down from their theoretical peak compression ratio so that they achieve somewhat reasonable compression in a time that is reasonable. With everything tuned to maximum compression you end up with massive ballooning memory requirements as well as memory bandwidth and CPU time. It can also require significantly higher resources to decompress as well.

Using "ultra" settings is only reasonable for data you want maximally compressed without time constraints and the results you are seeing reflect that. You are now hitting one of your system limitations as a result.

If you are simply sending the file to a friend and can tolerate a few percent larger file then chances are the "normal" settings would suffice.